# C++ copy constructor calling with object slicing

Tags: c++, inheritance, object-slicing

I wrote a C++ code snippet to test which copy constructor will be called during object slicing. The code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class pet
{
public:
  pet ()
  {
    cout << "pet default constructor" << '\n';
  }

  pet (pet & p)
  {
    cout << "pet copy constructor" << '\n';
  }

  ~pet ()
  {
    cout << "pet destructor" << '\n';
  }

  void speak ()
  {
    cout << "Growl" << '\n';
  }
};

class cat:public pet
{
public:
  cat ()
  {
    cout << "cat default constructor" << '\n';
  }

  cat (cat & c)
  {
    cout << "cat copy constructor" << '\n';
  }

  ~cat ()
  {
    cout << "cat destructor" << '\n';
  }

  void speak ()
  {
    cout << "Meow" << '\n';
  }
};

int main ()
{
  cat pussy;
  cout << "create pussy before this line" << '\n';
  ((pet) pussy).speak ();
  cout << "destroy pussy before leaving main()" << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

The output of this program is:

```
pet default constructor
cat default constructor
create pussy before this line
pet copy constructor
Growl
pet destructor
destroy pussy before leaving main()
cat destructor
pet destructor
```

I'm only interested in which copy constructor is called during object slicing, so let's focus only on the following part of the output:

```
pet copy constructor
Growl
pet destructor
```

I initially thought that when `(pet) pussy` is executed, the program would first call the cat copy constructor to create a temporary object, then remove the cat part (derived class part) of the temporary object and keep only the pet part (base class part). Therefore, I expected the output to be:

```
cat copy constructor
Growl
pet destructor
```

However, the actual output is different. Can you explain why this is the case? Thank you in advance for your answer.

###### Edit:

After reading the answer from @463035818_is_not_a_number, I realized that I had a misconception about the internal implementation of type casting. In fact, I'm not quite sure why pet& can be bound to a variable (pussy) of a different type, and what C++ does when implementing this feature.

Comment: `(pet) pussy` makes a `pet` from a `cat`. Why do you think another `cat` would be constructed?

Comment: The object `pussy` binds to the reference `p` in `pet::pet(pet & p)`

Comment: btw, avoid c-style casts, even when you slice on purpose. That line should be `(static_cast<pet>(pussy)).speak ();`

Comment: @Tommylee2k fwiw, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not. A single vote means nothing. You could as well ask "why was this upvoted?" and there is no definite answer other than "someone decided that this question deserves an upvote".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I initially thought that when (pet) pussy is executed, the program would first call the cat copy constructor to create a temporary object, then remove the cat part (derived class part) of the temporary object and keep only the pet part (base class part).

No. Thats not what happens. When you cast, like in this line (replaced c-style cast with proper one):

```
(static_cast<pet>(pussy)).speak ();
```

The the constructor will look for a conversion from `cat` to `pet`. The constructor `pet::pet(pet&)` can do that, because `pussy` can bind to `pet&`. No slicing is actually happening, no member data is lost. In other words, there are no members in `pussy` that get lost by calling this constructor.

On this temporary `pet` the member methods is called, then it is destroyed.

Comment: Oh! I think I had a misconception about the internal implementation of type casting. In fact, I'm not quite sure why pet& can be bound to variables (pussy) of different types. What does C++ do when implementing this method?

Comment: @jacky thats the basis of polymorphism. That you can do `Cat c; Pet& p = c;`. Frankly, its a bit odd that you know about slicing before inheritance

Answer (score 0):

Well your expected behavior is pretty strange: it implies, that you construct object of type A, yet destruct different object B in its place somehow.

In your code temporary object `pet` is constructed from `cat`, hence its copy constructor is called.